# is it good to pass large string or byte array around in multiple method calls

Tags: c#-4.0, methods, parameters, arrays

If I remember correctly even when we pass large string or byte array as a parameter to a method, it only passes the pointer to the heap of the data rather than the full data. So it should not degrade any performance or it should not pile up memory unnecessarily. Just want to confirm if my understanding is correct regarding the above statement?
I know it is better to keep the string or byte array as a private variable in the class and access it in every method it required thus eliminating one additional parameter from the method call.  

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If I remember correctly even when we pass large string or byte array as a parameter to a method, it only passes the pointer to the heap of the data rather than the full data.

Yes, when you pass *any* reference type argument, just the reference is passed, by value. Note that this is not the same as "pass by reference", which is applicable to parameters of both reference types and value types.

See my articles on [reference types and value types](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/references.html) and [parameter passing](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/parameters.html) for more information.

> I know it is better to keep the string or byte array as a private variable in the class and access it in every method it required thus eliminating one additional parameter from the method call.

That entirely depends on the context. Is it logically part of the state of the class or not?

Comment: Yes it part of the state but not part of the class. So correct to my statement, I have to pass this byte array to another class as well.

Comment: @Nair: If it's part of the state of the class, it should be a field in the class. It's still not really clear what you mean, to be honest...

Comment: The main class gets the large set of data, inside the class we have to instantiate couple of more classes where we need to pass this data around as we call methods of the instantiated class. Hope this is clear. ty